# How do I invoke/deploy a serverless function with diesel and mysql?

Tags: mysql, aws-lambda, rust, serverless-framework, rust-diesel

When I try to test out invoking a serverless function handler using the `serverless-rust` plugin I get the error

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlclient
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use the [hooks](https://github.com/softprops/lambda-rust#-using-hooks) in the `lambda-rust` docker builder to install the necessary dependencies and include the library files in the packaged build.

First create a directory at the root of the project named `.lambda-rust` and in it create two files:

`install`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "installing mysql dependencies"
yum install -y mysql-devel
```

and
`package`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "packaging mysql library"
zip -j "$1.zip" /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.18
```

Adjust the name of the library file for whichever is installed for you (I added a line with `echo $(ls /usr/lib64/mysql)` in one of the scripts to see what files existed after the install)